# Updating an imported .csv in Hyperion v8.3

Tags: csv, import, hyperion, brio

I have a csv imported into my Hyperion v8.3 bqy file.   I have some custom columns and a pivot already created.  I just want to refresh the data.  In the past, I would hit Process Current and it would direct me to my computer and I could select the csv file to update from.  Now it will not do that.  It doesn't go to my computer at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

I'm not a power user but I accomplish the same thing by ensuring that there is a file with the same name in the same location from which the original csv was imported and "Processing All".  This allows me to update the data and import it into my bqy and automatically update any reporting based on the csv.

Don't know if this will help or not.

Dennis
dennis.van.camp@vanderlande.com

Comment: Process All is likely to have significant consequences, depending on other sections in the document.  Only use that if you want to Process every Section in the document, in Section order.  Additionally, the OP wants to be prompted for a file.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a file as a Section into Hyperion, it maintains a link to the existing file for the exact path and file name.  When that link is broken and that section gets a Process or Refresh command, is the only time it will prompt you for a new file.  Otherwise, it will refresh the data from the existing.

So, if you want to force it to prompt you for a new file, you have to move or rename the old file.

But, you're looking for the Pivot and Computed columns to refresh.  Two things on that ...

> **Computed Columns:** You don't have to re-import the file, if the rest of your data is current.  Each column can be refreshed individually by right-click, Modify, then clicking Ok.  You don't have to change any of the code; just hit okay instead of Cancel.
>
> **Pivot:** In the menu, you have to set your pivot options appropriately to update when you Process (when the underlying data is Processed, really), or Manually (when you Process that section).